# How long would it take the internet to shut down if everyone else suddenly disappeared?

Tags: population, internet

Let's say you are browsing the internet, and the entire population of Earth instantly vanishes from existence. How long would it take before a link that you try to open fails?

Comment: Do you have a world that you're building, or is this out of curiosity?

Comment: "*Most people don’t even know what sysadmins do, but trust me, if they all took a lunch break at the same time they wouldn’t make it to the deli before you ran out of bullets protecting your canned goods from roving bands of mutants.*" [Programming Sucks](https://www.stilldrinking.org/programming-sucks)

Comment: How would I browse a link? I vanished with everybody else. I'm part of "*the entire population of Earth*"

Comment: Had this not been closed as a duplicate, it would have been closed for its lack of details. It's a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8262/40609), which is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer lies in Power!!**
As soon as the power goes out... NO internet...

Power has multiple points of failure so does the Internet.

Nuclear reactors, Hydro Power, Solar farms, Transformers, local power lines etc, they all need constant human maintenance, As soon as one of the crucial point goes out, its gone.

The same applies to the internet, It's just a connection of a bunch of servers and computers.
As soon as power to the server farms, routers and local service providers is cut, Internet goes out.

It also depends on your location, as power to your local service provider goes out before the server farm, or the server of your region goes off before other regions.